# setting extent using setExtent in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I want to make use of the `setExtent()` method in blackberry.

Every time i use `setExtent()`, it allocates the space from the zero, zero coordinate to any custom field that i paint by extending the `Field` class.

I want when I draw any custom field from (100,100), then it should allocate space from (100,100) and not from (0,0).

my code looks like:

```java
protected void layout(int width,int height)
{
    setExtent(100,100);
}
```

Please help me out with any solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you appear to be trying to do actually doesn't sound like a very good idea.  100 pixels is a useful measure on one device, but 100 pixels on a 9300 is over 1/3 of the height of the screen, but on a 9800 is no where near that. I would strongly recommend that you do not use fixed pixel sizes for any Blackberry development.

That said, if you want to Field to start at position 100,100, you should use setPositionChild for that Field in the Field's Manager.

Before you start leaping off attempting this, I would recommend that you review the following:
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-Extend-Manager/ta-p/446749
and
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Create-a-custom-layout-manager-for-a-screen/ta-p/442990

But perhaps the best options might be to explain what you are trying to achieve and we might be able to suggest an alternative.

Comment: Thanks.How can i trap events on a field.I have drawn two fields with graphics.drawRect(10,10,30,30),and graphics.drawRect(50,50,30,30) and now i want to trap individual events on these fields.How can i do that.

Comment: That is a different question and I suggest, worthy of a separate Thread.  When you post it, please indicate if you want to focus on these Fields using the trackpad or just via touch.  Again, I would not recommend using specific pixel sizes.